# How can the Model-View-Controller be adapted for OpenGL dependencies?

Tags: java, opengl, model-view-controller, resources, jogl

I'm developing an application which uses Java OpenGL in conjunction with the *Model-View-Controller* design pattern. Can anyone suggest a general mechanism by which vertex array objects used for rendering a particular graphical element can be re-used in conjunction with this pattern?

**Example:** Say I have data in my `Model` which provides some basic information about a number of individual `Polygon`s, which is detailed enough for my `View` to tessellate into a bunch of vertex array objects and render on the GPU. Is there a flexible pattern by which the `View` can re-use these VBOs between frames, without providing the `Model` with render-specific data?

I figured that I could create a `HashMap` which you could fetch the appropriate render data for a `Polygon`, but this would slow down rendering. This is because I'd first need to iterate through each `Polygon` I need to render, and then fetch the corresponding value in the `HashMap`. I could alternatively pass the `Polygon` a reference to the VBO, but this explicitly contravenes the *Model-View-Controller* design philosophy.

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63912/visitor-pattern-vs-inheritance-for-rendering

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a flexible pattern by which the View can re-use these VBOs between frames, without providing the Model with render-specific data?

[Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  Whenever a Model changes state it pokes any registered View(s) indicating which Model has changed.  Then the View can dump its cached version of the Model, query the newly changed Model, and (re)generate a new representation of it.

Comment: This is close, but how would you form an association between the new representation and it's corresponding source in the Model? I mean, are we supposed to treat the data we delegate to the VBOs as Model-type data?

Comment: @AlexT.: A HashMap or similar like you suggested (keyed off the Model reference and storing the OpenGL objects) in the View would probably work fine.

Comment: I think it might be a little slow. I mean, I have to iterate through a List of things I wish to render, then fetch elements out of that to look up in the HashMap. I think this would result in pretty poor performance in a GPU accelerated context. I've come up with one method which uses the Visitor pattern to slightly decouple entire dependence on HashMaps, but I'm starting to think it's unavoidable. This is a big problem with the MVC, people talk about it like it's incredible but it's definitely unintuitive and slower than the simpler encapsulation approach.

Comment: @AlexT. You mix up several concerns. Iterating on a list or a map is not the culprit. You should use some culling methods, with or without MVC. You should look at how it is handled in the numerous engines with a backend based on JogAmp.

Comment: @gouessej What do you mean culling methods? Also, although I've used Polygon as an example, really I'm talking about any GPU resource I'd like to persist between frames that I'd like to use with a corresponding construct in the Model.

Comment: Frustum culling? Contribution culling? Occlusion culling? If you're really concerned by the performance, you shouldn't send to the GPU too much things not visible and not drawn. I advise you to look at the design pattern "flyweight". You can store the mesh data (vertices, normals, indices, colors, tangents, ...) and the transforms (rotation, translation, scale, ...) into separate structures. Look at how JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation and JMonkeyEngine do that.

Comment: I think I should clarify. Basically, my application deploys a bunch of vertex data down to the GPU. This is based on information derived from my Model (I want to build a highly scalable application). I am looking to find a pattern which would allow me to avoid cross-coupling between OpenGL and my Model data as much as possible. JMonkeyEngine looks promising! http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:advanced:atom_framework:design:patterns